# Serial Number from custom table not appear in woocommerce_email_before_order_table action

Tags: plugin-development, customization, email, table

I have a custom table with serial numbers in WordPress. I have successfully got the serial number to appear on both Order received page after testing with Stripe:

[image]

and it also appears on WooCommerce Admin Orders Page:

[image]

I am using the **woocommerce_email_before_order_table** action. (on **customer_completed_order**)
I have the code below and I have echoed the Order ID and the Custom TableName and they BOTH appear in the Thanks for shopping with us email.
It seems the $license query returns nothing and I just can't see why it won't appear.
If I exchange the  $woo_order_id for the previous order no, like EMS-0051 the serial number appears.
Is this query too early and it hasn't been populated in the custom table before the query is run?
I cannot get it to work..can anyone see what I have done wrong, please?
The Thanks email and CODE is below.
[image: thanks 4 shopping with us]

```
<?php

add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'add_serial_to_email', 25, 4 ); 

function add_serial_to_email( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
   global $wpdb;
   $ipn_tables = $wpdb->prefix ."ipn_data_tbl";

 ///////BELOW is using 'seq Order No' plugin..this checks if WOO O/N or plugins O/N.
   if (empty($order->get_id))  {      
    $woo_order_id = $order->get_order_number();
      }             
 elseif (empty($order->get_order_number))  {
    $woo_order_id  = $order->get_id();
     }

 ///check order ID and Table name are there:
if (!empty($woo_order_id && $ipn_tables )) {
   echo '<b>ORDER ID:</b>  '.$woo_order_id.'<br>'; // echos the Order ID - appears on "Thanks for shopping with us" email
   echo '<b>TABLE NAME:</b>  '.$ipn_tables.'<br>';   // echo my Custom table name - appears on "Thanks for shopping with us" email
   ////But the below $licence variable dosent. I think its a timing thing. 
   //$license = $wpdb->get_var(" SELECT serial_no FROM $ipn_tables WHERE woo_order_id = $woo_order_id " );
   $license = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM {$ipn_tables} WHERE woo_order_id = %s", $woo_order_id ) );
      }

   if ( $email->id == 'customer_completed_order' ){
  
      printf( '<p class="custom-text">' .__( 'Your Software Serial Number:  '.'<span style="color:red;font-weight:bold;font-size:15px">'.$license ));
   } 
}//function-END
?>
```

Forgot to show MyPHPAdmin table:

[image]

edit:
I should have mentioned that I put that licenece check for orderID and table just to see if it was being checked..it appears my get_var query isn't working (empty?) but that same query is used in the other PHP pages I edited.

Comment: ```$license = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM {$ipn_tables} WHERE woo_order_id = %s", $woo_order_id ) ); ```

if I change that $woo_order_id to the PREVIOUS id .. the serial is printed in the email.
So it's almost like the data in woo_payment_complete goes into the custom table AFTER the email is sent which is weird as I thought the woo_payment_complete on successful transaction I have my table populate right away so I don't get why the serial is not found with above query esp. since tablename & ID are found.. it's weird. Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I found the issue. It was the fact that **'woocommerce_payment_complete'** hook
was too early **BUT** the hook '*woocommerce_pre_payment_complete*' is called ***first*** after payment is made but before order status change and before the email is sent. :)
So all I changed in the add_action was change:
woocommerce_payment_complete' TO woocommerce_pre_payment_complete that's it.
And it worked.
[part of the add_action updated code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJrB7.jpg)